# Ember navigates to a show route, GETs the wrong URL (/tools instead of /tools/1)

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a conventional Ember CLI app, and a conventional show route:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('tool', params.tool_id);
  }
});
```

But when I navigate to /tools/1, it GETs /tools instead of /tools/1! What am I doing wrong?

*Extra info...*

- I'm using the `--proxy http://127.0.0.1:3000` option to pass API requests to a Rails backend
- The app is organized in pods
- I have no custom adapters
- I know the route is being reached because I can add `.then(function() {debugger})` to the end of the promise and it gets hit
- Link to repo: https://github.com/jasonbenn/toolbus-web

Comment: Please show us the router entry for this route.

Comment: We don't have time to download your repo. Please post relevant code here, including the router definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tool` route is a parent to `tools.show`, so its model hook will also be hit in the process, and if the `tool` by that id is already fetched, it doesn't need to call your server again for `tools/1`

Comment: You're totally right, thanks for the help.  I need to change my API to include IDs and then add an async relationship to the model (or something along those lines - still reading the docs).